# Port 1227 for a web form

Tags: firewall, tcp

A Panamanian government website has a form that is on port 1227.  1227 is used for network administration (DNS).  Like most good companies, we blocks most non-standard ports, and before we open them we want to ensure that our network won't be compromised.  Is there any reason why a form would be on this port?

Comment: Don't *ever* post links like that on a public forum. We're indexed by Google and you're exposing yourself. Ask your administration.

Answer (score 2):

There's no (good) reason why they should be putting a web form on a non-standard port.
Unfortunately you can't control what other site admins elect to do though.